# PHP isset returning false when sending xhr with a file

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, upload

```
formdata.append('file', document.querySelector("#additional-image").files)
```

works file but when i do this:

```
formdata.append('file', document.querySelector("#additional-image").files[0])
```

the isset($_POST['file'] returns false

Answer (score 0):

Files won't be passed with $_POST.

Check $_FILES to get posted files data.

$_FILES is super global array which contains posted files to php script.

Comment: IT would be better if you elaborate your answer a little

Comment: How can i be so dumb? That's maybe the 3rd time this is happening to me!!! Thanks bro

Comment: $_FILES is superglobal array which contains files posted to php so u shud use it to get posted file details and not $_POST. You should not get confused to use post array as u r using post method to post the files.